# How to recover a forcibly deleted file in a git repository with NO commit history?

Tags: git

I performed the below steps -

1. Initialize a new git repository using `git init`.
2. Add some files to it.
3. Perform `git add`.
4. Delete a file using `git rm -f <fileName>`

How to retrieve the deleted file above here? Kindly note there are no commits yet.

Comment: you can't, it is gone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57652357/5170424 try this

Comment: One hope you have is that the file is still in the filecache of your editor. I had the luck once to find a needed file in the filecache of Notepad++.

Comment: @ShridharPatil There is no commits.

Comment: Always commit early and often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have run `git add`, the *content* of the file has been written in git objects store.

Run the following command :

```
git fsck --full --unreachable
# in the output, you should see lines looking like :
unreachable blob 08bf360988858a012dab3af4e0b0ea5f370a2ae8
unreachable blob 21bf7ea93f9f9cc2b3ecbed0e5ed4fa45c75eb89
unreachable blob 08c12ef37075732cf4645269ab5687ba6ba68943
...
```

Since you have no commit, you should have only a few lines like the above. You can inspect the content of each `blob` (a blob is a file in git parlance) :

```
git show 08bf360988858a012dab3af4e0b0ea5f370a2ae8
```

Once you have found the one you expect, just redirect the output :

```
git show 21bf7ea93f9f9cc2b3ecbed0e5ed4fa45c75eb89 > back-from-the-dead.txt
```

---

I have posted a few more details in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39469723/86072)